# manholes and plastic inspection chambers

Tags: plumbing

i am planning for new house construction and i live here in Oman Muscat, i want to ask you about
manholes and plastic inspection chambers, i want to make sure and ask about municipality rules,
there is very few info on this topic on the internet even if you search to read and get educated.
the house i want to build is so simple that it only have one bathroom and one outdoor sewer pipe.
i can change this main pipe to 4 inch or 6 inch diameter no problem.
concrete inspection chambers are the most obnoxious thing i will ever see in the setbacks.
as far as i have read you have to provide them at x meter of length of pipes and at every
turn on pipes and when main sewer connect to residential sewer...etc.
looking forward to use clean out system instead with plastic inspection chamber with one inlet and one outlet and non return valve at end of pipe when it connect to main public sewer.
but i have noticed some have different cover size 200mm, 300mm, 400mm.
i don't even know which one should i use for my project and i don't even know
what adoptable and non adoptable sewer means please advice.

Comment: "i want to make sure and ask about municipality rules" Honestly, your best bet is going to be going to your local building commission and asking them. It's highly unlikely (though anything's possible) that anyone here is going to be familiar with building codes in Oman. I believe your "concrete inspection chambers" would be outside (in the yard?). Here in the US, a clean-out (access to the pipe) is _recommended_, but I don't know that they're required at every bend as they seem to be in Oman.

Comment: Maybe talk with your builder about the options, as he should be familiar with local building codes and what your options are.

Comment: Your local inspectors(building, health(plumbing)) are the ones to ask if plastic ones would be okay instead of cement ones.

Comment: As others have said: Consult the Local Authority Having Jurisdiction, or trust that your builder will do so, or pester your builder to do so.